# Rotate scene around object at centre

Tags: opengl, camera, glulookat

I have an object which is at (0.0, 0.0, -39.0) and never moves, the rest of the scene moves relative to this object; I want the camera to look at this object and at the same direction.  When I do this:

```
gluLookAt(0.0, 120.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, -39.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
drawobject();
glTranslatef(0.0, y, 0.0);
glRotatef(angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
drawScene();
```

instead of scene rotating around object (actually around world z-axis), it rotates around its center. If I change the order of translation and rotation then it rotates around object correctly, but it translates in the direction of scene y-direction (I want it translate towards world y-direction). I think I know why this happens, but I don't know how to fix it. I guess I have made myself confused XD.

I should add that I use arrow keys to get input from user to change "y" and "angle". So, basically if this object is the player, I want the camera look at its back at all times, and player can move around using the keyboard. However, instead of moving the player, I decided to move the scene. I am not sure if this is the standard approach though.

Comment: I find your question very vague, but it seems that you are forgetting that the transformations are cumulative. Try rethinking the order of the operations and the reference for each object/scene draw-call. And more: be sure that your `drawScene();` and `drawobject();` routines respects the matrix stack, ie: they don't call `glLoadIdentity()` and things like that.

Comment: @Kahler -Thanks for the comment and sorry for my vague question. My draw functions don't have any transformations inside them, and, I only used glLoadIdentity() before glulookat.